# XCode won't build suddenly (4.3.3)

Tags: xcode, build

I went to build project and get message all sudden. Don't know what issue may be?

> Unable to resolve Interface Builder plug-in dependency for
>   "MainMenu.xib". Xcode 4 is missing components necessary to load the
>   following class: SCNViewTemplate. Ensure that Xcode has been properly
>   installed.

Answer (score 0):

SCNViewTemplate / SceneKit is only available in Mac OS X 10.8.